# Syntax error near the keyword order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I perform this query

```
SELECT 
   orders.id, orders.order - time, orders.pizza.id, 
   orders.pizza.type, orders.pizza-size, orders.quantity, 
FROM 
   orders 
INNER JOIN 
   permit ON orders.id = pizza.id 
WHERE 
   ([username] = @username)
```

I get an error

> Syntax error near the keyword order

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: `FROM orders INNER JOIN permit ON orders.id = pizza.id` Replace pizza with permit.Also what is your database,mysql,sql server,oracle?Put your column names in brackets `orders.[order-time]`,assuming sql server.

Comment: i'm using vb then connect to a sql database created within visual studio

Comment: now i get this error message 'Invalid object name 'permit'.'

Comment: **Every** relational databases is "*a SQL database*" - SQL is just a query language not a specific DBMS product. Based on the (non-standard) syntax in your query and your comment I added the `sql-server` and `tsql` tags

Comment: Well then maybe there is not a table named permit.  And pizza come out of no where.  You cannot have a pizza.id without a pizza

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no `order by` clause and the error message is complaining about your statement near the `order` keyword, I surmise that there are two possibilities.

The first is that you've left the `s` of one of your table specifiers, using `order` instead of `orders`, despite your transcription.

The second is that `orders.order-time` is incorrect, being treated as `orders.order - time`. In fact, I'd be a little worried by many of your names, including those that have two periods (`.`) in them. You may want to check if the `-` and the subsequent `.` characters should be underscores (`_`) instead.

You also have a trailing comma after the last column selection (before the `from`), which is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL-Server

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.[order-time], orders.[pizza.id], orders.[pizza.type], orders.[pizza-size], orders.quantity, 
  FROM orders INNER JOIN permit ON orders.id = pizza.id 
 WHERE ([username] = @username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma after the final column before `FROM`.

Also could you explain what the `">` on the end is for, was this pasted in error?

Comment: after i remove the comma, it still generates an error message

Comment: @user3607224 what error message do you get now?

Comment: @ChrisProsser The error message in the question title is caused by an error that you didn't address (`orders.order-time`). I'm not answering, though, because there are too many other problems that I don't know how to give a good and useful answer.

Comment: the > is for the sqldatasource tag that i'm using on visual studio to generate certain values from a table